# Any way to avoid assignment in c++ constructor body?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am implementing a class `request`, the constructor of which takes a command line as its argument, and the class has file status like file size, last modified time, etc., as its fields.

I want to assign values to these fields, and it involves calling `fstat()`, accessing values in the `struct stat`, and using these values.

I know that assignments in c++ constructor is discouraged, and initialization list should be used, but I have no idea how to assign values to these fields without calling functions in the constructor body(between brackets) and using the assignment operator.

What should I do?

If I have to initialize them in the constructor body, should I first initialize all the fields using `NULL`(which I think is done by default)?

---

```
class request {
    vector<string> requests;
    off_t content_length;
    char* last_modified;

    public:

    explicit request(char line[]): requests(split_string(line)), content_length(NULL), last_modified(NULL) {
        struct stat sb;
        if(fstat(line[1], &sb) == -1) {
            cerr << "Error while getting file status of the file named " << line[1] << endl;
        }

        content_length = sb.st_size;
        last_modified = ctime(&sb.st_mtime);
    }
};
```

This is my code. Do they look fine?

Comment: initialize them in the body, it is there for a reason.

Comment: Yes, you can first initialize the fields with NULL, and assign it to the value in another help function. It's a good style to do as few things as possible in the constructor function.

Comment: It might be best to post the code that uses assignments in the ctor body and ask for improvement ideas that might make use of direct initialization.  Frankly, for things like file size and last modified time, you're likely to have no problems with assignment in the ctor body since these are probably built-in types (or close to it).  Also, keep in mind that rules such as "don't assign in the ctor" can be broken with reasonable justification.

Comment: I would not worry about it. Unless this is heavily used code in time critical operations the difference is trivial. Focus on writing working, robust, readable code that you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using initialization lists for members has a couple of advantages over assignment within a constructor:

- Member variables with constructors are only constructed once.
- This is the only way `const` members can be initialized.

However, there's nothing *wrong* with initializing in the body, if initialization is too complex to take place in the constructor.

Members are *not* initialized to NULL by default.  Member variables that have constructors (i.e., non-POD types) are default-initialized, but that's all.

One approach to doing complex initialization and still doing it within the initializer list is to use a helper function.

```
Example::Example()
  : file_size_(CalculateFileSize())
{
};

int Example::CalculateFileSize()
{
  // Complex initialization here.
  // Be careful - this instance isn't fully initialized yet.
}
```

This approach is generally not as clear as just doing it in the constructor body, so I'd only recommend it if you really need to do everything in the initializer list (for example, if you're using `const` member variables).  Also note that you can only cleanly use it to initialize one member variable at a time.

Comment: Thank you. I was going to use helper function for some fields, then I realized it makes the parameter list of the helper function messy, or it has to call fstat() multiple times unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the assignments per se. The reason why it is *recommended* to use initialization lists is for members that are "costly" to construct because in case of assigning in the constructor body you pay twice: once to construct the member using the default constructor and then to assign to it.

So if you have a special member that is difficult to initialize with a simple expression, don't kill yourself over this - initialize it in the body. One thing you might want to do it to make it's (that is, that member's) default constructor *cheap* which will eliminate the problem.

There are also exception handling connotations related to the two methods but I don't think they are relevant in your case.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with constructor bodies, especially if exceptions are allowed in your program. The more important rule here is RAII.

I would do something like the following:

```
class request
{
  public:
    request (int fildes)
      : size(0)
      , last_modified_time(EPOCH)
    {
      struct stat statistics;
      auto error = fstat(&statistics);

      if (not error) {
          size = statistics.st_size;
          last_modified_time = statistics.st_mtimespec;
          // ...
      } else {
          // Note: if exceptions are not okay for you, then you need to move this
          // entire body to an Initialize() function that returns an error
          // indicator. This pattern is called two-phase initialization.
          //
          throw std::runtime_error("Hard disk is broken?!");
      }
    }
}
```